# Tokens getting ignored in Antlr4

Tags: parsing, preprocessor, antlr

I am currently trying to parse `preprocessor defines` in c files with Antlr. Currently I just want to fetch the define `name` and `value` (if any).

this is aproximately how my current code looks like...

```
statement : ppdefine (LINEBREAK | defValue);
defValue : DEFINEVALUE;
ppdefine : PREPROCESS ;

DEFINEVALUE : VALUE;
PREPROCESS : PPDEFINE;            
PPDEFINE : PP  WS* DEFINER WS+ VALUE;

//Some basic types...
TEXT : (VALUE|STAR|LETTERSIGN|WS)+ -> skip;
LINEBREAK : [\r]? [\n] ->skip;
PP : [#] -> skip;
DEFINER : 'define';
VALUE : (LETTER|NUMBER)+ -> skip;

....  //Several more lines that look similar
```

When I run this on my file, I only receive `"#define"` + its `name` as a token and am missing the value if there is one. How can I receive the value in another token?

If you want an example file try this:

```
#define DEF1 1
#define DEF2 2
```

Comment: Any reason you're skipping everything? Doesn't make sense to skip useful tokens like `PP` and `VALUE`.

Comment: I have a lot more in my real files than only defines as they are c files. If I dont skip for example the `VALUE` I get some additional Tokens in my tree that I dont need and I am not able to find a way to have my value behind my define, but no additional tokens.